# How can I disable horizontal scrolling in a WPF ListBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, listbox

This seems to be an absurdly simple question but Google and Stack Overflow searches yield nothing. How can I disable horizontal scrolling in a WPF [ListBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listbox) when items take up more horizontal space than is available in the box?

Answer (score 302, accepted):

In XAML:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
```

In C#:

```
myListBox.SetValue(
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibilityProperty,
    ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled);
```

Comment: If it doesn't work for you then use this simple answer >> https://stackoverflow.com/a/1739298/2123400

Comment: @Eftekhari Thank you, you have helped me solve a problem that has been bothering me for weeks!

Comment: @CodingNinja You are welcome, :) That's why we need personal AI

Answer (score 1):

If you created the Listbox from codebehind and want to make the change in XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" x:Key="{x:Type ListBox}" >
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```