# How to disable ScrollViewer in ListBox?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, scrollviewer

I have a ListBox. It has internal ScrollViewer, so I can scroll ListBox content with mouse wheel. It works fine until I set item template that contains another ListBox (in fact, I have 4 nested ListBoxes =)). Problem is that internal ListBox's ScrollViewer steals wheeling event. Is there any easy way to prevent this behavior?

---

I had ListBox with ItemContainerStyle like this:

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
     ... 
</Style>
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}" />
```

How can I set style for ItemContainer's item border in resources like this? As I know ContentPresenter is item container of ItemsControl. But it hasn't Border, so I can't style it.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can remove the `ScrollViewer` from a `ListBox` by changing its control template to something much simpler:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ItemsPresenter />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListBox.Template>
    ...
</ListBox>
```

However, I question the value of nesting ListBoxes. Remember that each `ListBox` is a Selector and has a concept of which item is "selected". Does it really make sense to have a selected item inside a selected item, inside a selected item?

I would suggest changing the "inner" `ListBoxes` to simple `ItemsControls` so that the nested lists can't have selected items. That would make for a much simpler user experience. You may still need to retemplate the inner `ItemsControls` in the same way to remove the scrollbars, but at least the user won't get confused about which item is "selected".

Comment: _Does it really make sense to have a selected item inside a selected item, inside a selected item?_ Yes. How else would you select an item from a list inside a list inside a list?

Comment: this also removes a lot of other stuff from the listbox as well, e.g. drop-events

Comment: @wotanii did you find a solution that does not remove drop-events? (im using touch to scroll)

Comment: Selecting an item from a list inside a list inside a list ?  Isn't that what Treeviews are for?

Answer (score 16):

You can disable stealing scroll events by catching scroll event in XAML:

```
<ListBox PreviewMouseWheel="ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel">
```

and re-publishing it in Code behind:

```
private void ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is ListBox && !e.Handled)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            var eventArg = new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta);
            eventArg.RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseWheelEvent;
            eventArg.Source = sender;
            var parent = ((Control)sender).Parent as UIElement;
            parent.RaiseEvent(eventArg);
        }
    }
```

The solution is exactly for ListBox, it helped me with ListView.

I found this solution here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3a3bb6b0-e088-494d-8ef2-60814415fd89/swallowing-mouse-scroll?forum=wpf

Comment: Thanks! Been looking for a long time now. It works!

Comment: How would you solve this if use you were using touch to scroll instead of the mouse wheel?

Comment: I don't have ready solution and cannot test it but I'd start looking for similar touchscreen related events and republish them alike the solution I'd reposted.

Answer (score 4):

I like to create a behavior for this type of thing.

xmlns:bhv="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <bhv:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <bhvs:NoScrollingBehavior/>
    </bhv:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ListView>
```

The behavior itself.

```
public class NoScrollingBehavior : Behavior<UIElement>
{
    public NoScrollingBehavior()
    { }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseWheel += PreviewMouseWheel;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseWheel -= PreviewMouseWheel;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        var eventArg = new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta);
        eventArg.RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseWheelEvent;
        eventArg.Source = sender;
        var parent = ((Control)sender).Parent as UIElement;
        parent.RaiseEvent(eventArg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a solution using MVVM !

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for waking up such a old post. Actually, you can disable the ScrollViewer by using ScrollViewer's attached property.

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ...
</ListBox>
```

Comment: This still seems to steal the wheeling event

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variant with DependencyProperty, if you don't like behaviors

```cs
public class IgnoreScrollingBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IgnoreScrollingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IgnoreScrolling", typeof(bool),
            typeof(IgnoreScrollingBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIgnoreScrollingChanged));

    public static bool GetIgnoreScrolling(UIElement uIElement)
    {
        return (bool)uIElement.GetValue(IgnoreScrollingProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIgnoreScrolling(UIElement uIElement, bool value)
    {
        uIElement.SetValue(IgnoreScrollingProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnIgnoreScrollingChanged(DependencyObject depOpj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (depOpj is not UIElement item)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (e.NewValue is bool boolean)
        {
            if (boolean)
            {
                item.PreviewMouseWheel += OnPreviewMouseWheel;
            }
            else
            {
                item.PreviewMouseWheel -= OnPreviewMouseWheel;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void OnPreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        MouseWheelEventArgs eventArg = new(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta)
        {
            RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseWheelEvent,
            Source = sender
        };
        UIElement parent = ((Control)sender).Parent as UIElement;
        parent.RaiseEvent(eventArg);
    }
}
```

This is how it is used

```xml
<Listbox b:IgnoreScrollingBehavior.IgnoreScrolling="True".../>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this ! No Wheel stolen.

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ...
</ListBox>
```