# How to disable mouse wheel scroll in listbox in silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am not able to disable default behavior of mouse wheel scrolling in listbox control of silverlight 4 and apply my custom scrolling animation to listbox on mousewheel event. When I added my animation to mouse wheel event of listbox, first list box items get scrolled according to mouse wheel movement and then my custom animation to scroll list box items get fired. Please ans my query.

Comment: I cant remove the scrollviewer inside the listbox control since I'm animating the vertical offset of scrollviewer for animated scrolling. So any other suggestions please.

Comment: The problem *is* the ScrollViewer. You *can* animate an offset on other container types. You do not need to animate a ScrollViewer, so get rid of it and use another container (or containers).

Answer (score 1):

I could not find any easy way to just turn it off, but you can change the template of the listbox to use a different container (it uses a ScrollViewer internally).

The simplest version like this is [from another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739216/how-to-disable-scrollviewer-in-listbox):

```
<ListBox.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <ItemsPresenter />
    </ControlTemplate>
</ListBox.Template>
```

You really need expression Blend to make changes to a full template as a ListBox template looks like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationToolTipTemplate">
            <Grid x:Name="Root" Margin="5,0" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0">
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="xform" X="-25"/>
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="OpenStates">
                        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="Open">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="xform">
                                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            <BackEase Amplitude=".3" EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    </DoubleAnimation>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Root"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualTransition>
                        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Root"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Open">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="xform"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Root"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Border Background="#052A2E31" CornerRadius="5" Margin="4,4,-4,-4"/>
                <Border Background="#152A2E31" CornerRadius="4" Margin="3,3,-3,-3"/>
                <Border Background="#252A2E31" CornerRadius="3" Margin="2,2,-2,-2"/>
                <Border Background="#352A2E31" CornerRadius="2" Margin="1,1,-1,-1"/>
                <Border Background="#FFDC000C" CornerRadius="2"/>
                <Border CornerRadius="2">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" MaxWidth="250" Margin="8,4,8,4" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" UseLayoutRounding="false"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle1" TargetType="ListBox">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="2">
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}">
                                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                            <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" BorderBrush="#FFDB000C" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="2" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                    <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Template="{StaticResource ValidationToolTipTemplate}">
                                        <ToolTip.Triggers>
                                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                    <System:Boolean>true</System:Boolean>
                                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </BeginStoryboard>
                                            </EventTrigger>
                                        </ToolTip.Triggers>
                                    </ToolTip>
                                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                <Grid Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="10" Margin="0,-4,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="10">
                                    <Path Data="M 1,0 L6,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 8,2 L8,7 z" Fill="#FFDC000C" Margin="-1,3,0,0"/>
                                    <Path Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 8,6 L8,8" Fill="#ffffff" Margin="-1,3,0,0"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: on the `layoutUpdate` event get the `ScrollContentPresenter` from the `scrollview`:

```
private ScrollContentPresenter Scp;    
void ScrollView_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Scp == null)
        {
            try
            {

                FrameworkElement myFE = (FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(ScrollView, 0);
                Scp = (ScrollContentPresenter)myFE.FindName("ScrollContentPresenter");
                Scp.MouseWheel += new MouseWheelEventHandler(Scp_MouseWheel);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {


            }
        }
```

And then in the Scp MouseWheel event:

```
void Scp_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```